# HTML Canvas & Javascript - Shadow Around Image Rather Than Border

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I am trying to draw a shadow behind the border of a curved rectangle containing an image. The code below, however, puts the shadow behind the image rather than the border. How can I change this code such that the shadow is behind the border?

To clarify, the border is currently shadowed by the image shadow, but I do not want the image to have **any** shadow. It is the white border surrounding the image that I would like to have a shadow. I do not wish to have a shadow surrounding the canvas but the curved rectangular border **within** the canvas.

```js
var c=document.getElementById('game'),
  canvasX=c.offsetLeft,
  canvasY=c.offsetTop,
  ctx=c.getContext('2d')
  elements = [];
    
var x=25, y=25, w=150, h=150;

var img=new Image(); 
img.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddSWa.jpg';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth='8';
ctx.strokeStyle='white';
ctx.moveTo(x+10, y);
ctx.lineTo(x+w-10, y);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y, x+w, y+10);
ctx.lineTo(x+w, y+h-10);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y+h, x+w-10, y+h);
ctx.lineTo(x+10, y+h);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y+h, x, y+h-10);
ctx.lineTo(x, y+10);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x+10, y);
ctx.shadowColor = '#000000';
ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 5;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 5;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.drawImage(img, x+2.5, y+2.5, w-5, h-5);
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #FF9900;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>uTalk Demo</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='game.css' media='screen'></style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="game" width = "200" height = "200"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So sorry for my answer, deleted it, but put that in your question, the within

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the shadowOffset before drawing your image. 
When you set this property, all subsequent drawings will have a shadow.

```js
var c=document.getElementById('game'),
  canvasX=c.offsetLeft,
  canvasY=c.offsetTop,
  ctx=c.getContext('2d')
  elements = [];
    
var x=25, y=25, w=150, h=150;

var img=new Image(); 
img.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddSWa.jpg';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth='8';
ctx.strokeStyle='white';
ctx.moveTo(x+10, y);
ctx.lineTo(x+w-10, y);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y, x+w, y+10);
ctx.lineTo(x+w, y+h-10);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y+h, x+w-10, y+h);
ctx.lineTo(x+10, y+h);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y+h, x, y+h-10);
ctx.lineTo(x, y+10);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x+10, y);
ctx.shadowColor = '#000000';
ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 5;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 5;
ctx.stroke();
// now reset the shadow
ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;

ctx.drawImage(img, x+2.5, y+2.5, w-5, h-5);
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #FF9900;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>uTalk Demo</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='game.css' media='screen'></style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="game" width = "200" height = "200"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The shape you are drawing is just an image and not a `border`. It will only remain inside the canvas. But if you do something like this, you just need to play with the `x,y coordinates`. Otherwise, you can use `border` and `box-shadow` property

```js
var c=document.getElementById('game'),
  canvasX=c.offsetLeft,
  canvasY=c.offsetTop,
  ctx=c.getContext('2d')
  elements = [];
    
var x= 20, y=20, w=160, h=160;

var img=new Image(); 
img.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddSWa.jpg';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth='8';
ctx.strokeStyle='white';
ctx.moveTo(x+10, y);
ctx.lineTo(x+w-10, y);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y, x+w, y+10);
ctx.lineTo(x+w, y+h-10);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y+h, x+w-10, y+h);
ctx.lineTo(x+10, y+h);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y+h, x, y+h-10);
ctx.lineTo(x, y+10);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x+10, y);
ctx.shadowColor = '#000000';
ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 5;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 5;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.drawImage(img, x+27.5, y+27.5, w-55, h-55);
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>uTalk Demo</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='game.css' media='screen'></style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="game" width = "200" height = "200"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I think my question must not have been clear enough. I have added some extra detail to it but Kaiido's answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you need. I don't see any problem with your code. Have you tried to use:

```
ctx.strokeStyle = 'grey'; //or the color you want.
ctx.lineWidth = 5; //For thickness
```